# Draw Graph with upper and lower limit

Tags: plotting, graphics, design-patterns

I am attempting to draw a graph with a slope of 200,000 that becomes "saturated" at $y= \pm 10$. Essentially, the graph is of the form $y=200000x$. However, I have been unsuccessful in getting it to level off at the y bounds. I want the graph to become a horizontal straight lines at those values, like this, where my A would be 200000 and my Vcc values would be $\pm 10$:

[image: from a random website]

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
x0 = First[x /. Solve[2 10^5 x == 10]]
```

> 1/20000

```
y[x_] := Piecewise[{{2 10^5 x, -x0 < x < x0}, {10, x >= x0}, {-10, x <= x0}}]

plot = Plot[y[x], {x, -2 x0, 2 x0}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

---

Or in another way, using `Clip` as requested by [C. E.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126067/draw-graph-with-upper-and-lower-limit#comment341215_126069):

```
Plot[Clip[200000 x, {-10, 10}], {x, -2 x0, 2 x0}, Frame -> True]
```

which gives the same plot as above.

Comment: Oh that's brilliant. Totally forgot about piecewise functions. Thanks so much!

Comment: Since you've answered this question and it has already been accepted, would you mind also writing about `Clip`?